# Internet sharing issue with Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: windows-10, internet-sharing

My android device whose android version is 4.4.2.

It does support USB Internet (sharing Windows PC internet via USB cable).

For this I need to setup Internet Sharing in Windows 10 Desktop Computer.

While setting up Internet Sharing, I see following error.

[image]

Please let me know, how to fix it and how to setup?

Regards

FewL

Comment: In your screenshot you haven't yet chosen network connection to share. See where it says "Select a private network connection"? Have you tried selecting your network connection from that dropdown menu?

Comment: In my desktop computer, VMware Workstation is installed. Therefore, I see VMware Network Adaptor VNet1 and VMware Network Adaptor VNet8 in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers required to enable USB Internet interface, maybe missing, try installing the android drivers properly. Once done if you enable USB Internet from your android device, it gets assigned an interface usually **RNDIS interface**:

[image]

Alternatively if you have problems, you  can try 3rd party software like [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) (which installs drivers ) and get you get an interface, which can then enable you to share the internet from ICS

A sequence of steps lets you have the appropriate USB drivers:

Select appropriate USB driver from list:

[image]

The installation begins..

[image]

Be sure to give permission to install these certified drivers

[image]

The network driver is also installed,

[image]

The consequence of this is that a new interface is established, from from you can use in ISC (**PdaNet Broadband adapter**):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you did not select anything in the "Home networking connection" dropdown menu in your screenshot. You need to select the connection you want to share the internet with.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1115839)